# vb.net child form falls behind panel control inside parent form

Tags: vb.net, panel, mdichild, mdiparent

I am in a bit of a bother. I have a MDI.Parent form within it some blue pannels. When I call my child form, the child form falls behind the blue panels. I didn't expect this because the panels already existed at runtime whilst the child form is called latter (I though namely that new items alway ended up on top).

How do I fix this... Im using Vb.net for this

Comment: MDI is old... Add the child form directly as a control instead via `Me.Controls.Add(yourForm)`.

Comment: You must dock the panels to an edge of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to fix.  That's the way it works.

When you set the `IsMdiContainer` property of a form to `True`, what actually happens is an `MdiClient` control is added to your form to act as a host for the child forms.  The grey background you see is actually that control, not the form.  When you add an MDI child form to the parent, is becomes a child control of that `MdiClient`.

If you were to add a `GroupBox` to your form and put a `Panel` over it and then add a `Button` to the `GroupBox`, would you expect the `Button` to be visible over the `Panel`?  I would hope not, because it won't.  This is no different.

The child form is basically part of the `MdiClient` control so anything that covers that covers the child form too.  If you're trying to do otherwise then you're abusing MDI.  You can add `Panels` and dock them to the edges of the parent form but you're not supposed to have floating controls.

With a bit of jiggery-pokery you can display an `Image` as a background or draw a gradient or the like but the `MdiClient` was not designed to host controls other than forms so you can't add controls to it either.

Comment: Jmcilhinney that makes sense. The other thing i have tried is to create a child form at load that holds the blue panels then load the "Pen styles" form as before. Though this dose work I need the new child form to be maximized however this causes my "Pen Styles" child to also become maximized dispute setting its minimum and maximum size equally to 260;300....?